# Method to reverse a queue

Tags: queue, reverse

i got the following class for the queue.

```
public class queueArray {

    final int maxNumbers=1000;
    protected Item[] arrayInfo;
    protected int head ,tail;

    public queueArray(){
        head=tail=0;
        arrayInfo= new Item[maxNumbers];
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return(head==tail && arrayInfo[tail]==null);
    }

    public void insert(Item a){
        if(head == tail && arrayInfo[tail]!=null){
            System.out.println("Η ουρά είναι γεμάτη.");
            return;
        }
        arrayInfo[tail]=a;
        tail=(tail+1)%maxNumbers;
    }

    public Item removeFirst(){
        if (head == tail && arrayInfo[head]!=null){
            System.out.println("Η ουρά είναι γεμάτη.");
            return null;
        }
        arrayInfo[head]=null;
        head=(head+1)%maxNumbers;
        return arrayInfo[head];
    }
}
```

How can i made an extra method that reverses queue's clues?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the .NET Queue class, then you can just call Reverse() for example:

```
            Queue<int> q = new Queue<int>();  
            q.Enqueue(1);  
            q.Enqueue(2);  
            q.Enqueue(15);  
            q.Enqueue(22);  

            q.Reverse();
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be to pull all of the elements from the front of the queue and push them to a stack. Then pull from the top of the stack and push those elements back to the queue.